# app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, build.gradle

I have run yesterday react-native projects and the error is`app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED.`.

Comment: [Try this steps](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35204). It is look like general problem.

Comment: My problem solved from here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210